# Como acessar a aba Data de dentro do Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio

Olá, estou com um problema que não consigo acessar a minha aba, mesmo usando o emulador ou um dispositivo físico conectado ao PC com um USB. Esse erro pode ser devido a alguma permissão, mas não sei como solucionar.

O que deveria ocorrer seria algo semelhante a esse vídeo, que pode ser acessado nesse link; https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud845/lessons/f5bb088f-6cc0-4e7d-9985-1418654bb141/concepts/1e184436-fa22-4d9b-bae3-45413068a791

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para acessar esta pasta, precisa de root. Mas é estranho no emulador não deixar, apesar que teve uma mudança nestas permissões nas imagens mais novas dos emuladores.

Comment: Com essas mudanças, o que devo fazer para permitir o acesso e seu quiser acessar pelo Root, que passos devo seguir para libera-lo no meu dispositivo móvel?